# Using numpy.median on a masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a little confused about the output of numpy.median in the case of masked arrays.  Here is a simple example (assuming numpy is imported - I have version 1.6.2):

```
>>> a = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, numpy.nan]
>>> am = numpy.ma.masked_array(a, [numpy.isnan(x) for x in a])
```

I'd like to be able to use the masked array to ignore `nan`values in the array when calculating the median.   This works for mean using either `numpy.mean` or the `mean()` method of the masked array:

```
>>> numpy.mean(a)
nan
>>> numpy.mean(am)
4.5
>>> am.mean()
4.5
```

However for median I get:

```
>>> numpy.median(am)
5.0
```

but I'd expect something more like this result:

```
>>> numpy.median([x for x in a if not numpy.isnan(x)])
4.5
```

and unfortunately a `masked_array` does not have a `median` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `np.ma.median` on a `MaskedArray`.

[*Explanation: If I remember correctly, the `np.median` does not support subclasses, so it fails to work correctly on `np.ma.MaskedArray`.*]

Comment: @PaulJoireman You're welcome. More often than not, the `np.ma` module implements the equivalent of `numpy` functions, adpated to `MaskedArray`.